# Find the solution set of $|z-1| = 1$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Find the solution set of $|z-1| = 1$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$

This is what I did:

---

$$\begin{align} 
|z-1| = 1 &\implies |z-1|^2 = 1^2 \\
&\implies |(z-1)^2| = 1 \\
&\implies z^2 -2z = 0 \\
&\implies z(z-2) = 0 \\
&\implies x+iy = 0 \ \ \ \ \lor \ \ \ \ x+iy  = 2 \ \ \ \\\
&\implies (x = 0 \ \ \land\ \ y = 0) \lor (x=2 \land y = 0)
\end{align}$$

Thus the solution to $|z-1| = 1$ are the point $(0,0)$ and $(2, 0)$ on the complex plane.

---

**EDIT:** It is clear that this is not the full solution set? But why does approaching this algebraically as I did, not yield a full solution set? Or has it yielded a full solution set and I've just interpreted things wrong?

Comment: you can tell that your answer is incomplete by the fact that (2,0) is a valid solution as well (and not just those) so your question should be more about finding the correct solution than a more succinct way to do so.

Comment: Can you interpret the solution(s) to the equation geometrically?

Comment: Hint: $z = 1+i$ is obviously a solution. Try to find the step where equality breaks.

Comment: There are is a small and a large error. In the third equation, you forgot the $1$ on the right. But, the main problem is that for complex numbers it is not true that $|a^2| = a^2$ for complex $a$.

Comment: @Perturbative. Here is something to think about: What is the graph of $|z|=1$? and how does this graph relate to your formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=x+i*y$, where $i^2=-1$.  Then we have

$$1=|z-1|=|x+iy-1|=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},$$

so squaring both sides leads to the equation

$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1.$$

This is the equation of a circle of radius 1, centered at the point $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$|z-1|=1$ means the distance from the point $(1,0)$ is 1.

Can you write down the equation of circle centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $1$?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't found all solutions.

A different approach is to approach it geometrically. The modulus in your question must be one so this represents a circle with radius of 1 (as you don't care about the argument). The circle is centered where $z-1=0$ hence at $(1,0)$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the step of $$|z^2 + 2z + 1| = 1 \implies z^2 + 2z -1 = 0$$ is incorrect. Remember, $|z|$ is the *magnitude* of $z$.

One way to do this is to write $z = x + iy$, and then solve

$$
|(x + iy) - 1| = 1 \\
|(x - 1) + iy| = 1 \\
(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1 \\
(x - 1)^2 + (y - 0)^2 = 1
$$

Which is the equation of a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(1, 0)$

You can imagine this by thinking of a complex number $z$, that is free to sit anywhere in 2D. Then you limit its distance from the point $1 + 0i$ to be $1$, which is exactly the circle of radius 1 centered at $(1, 0)$

Comment: Are you then saying that $|z^2| \neq z^2$ if $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes, $|z^2|$ is a real number, while $z^2$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Use *exponential form*: the set $\mathbf U$ of complex numbers with  modulus $1$ is simply $\;\bigl\{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mkern1.5mu\theta}\mid\theta\in]-\pi,\pi]\bigr\}$. So the solutions are
$$\bigl\{1+\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mkern1.5mu\theta}\mid\theta\in]-\pi,\pi]\bigr\}.$$